# How can I send a table through the PHP mail function?

Tags: php, email

How do I create and send an [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) table in the body of an email through the PHP `mail()` function?

Comment: do you want to send mail with html tables in it?

Comment: Yes
Have already figured out a way to do it
sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$to = "to@example.com, anotherto@example.com";
$subject = "HTML email";

$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>XXXX</th>
<th>XXXX</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>XXXX</td>
<td>XXXX</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <from@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: cc@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to not use the mail function. What i can recommend is using swiftmailer. Works great, is easy to install and you can use html easily.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is adding an HTML table in the body, content type in the header, and use a header in the mail function. For example:

```
// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// Send mail with header
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Alternatively, you could use

1. [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)
2. [PHP Mailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Answer (score 1):

Use the PHP mail function and set the header as `text/html`:

```
<?php
    $to = "to@yoyr-destin.com";
    $from = "your@doamin.com";
    $subject = "Mail with html content";

    $message = <<<EOF

    <html>
        <body>
            <table>
                   <!-- Your table goes here -->
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
    EOF;

    $headers  = "From: $from\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    echo "Mail has been sent successfully!";
?>
```